# Ubuntu not installing/problems with trying ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, system-installation, lubuntu

Ok so for the past 2 days I have been trying to get ANY ubuntu 16.04 version to work. (Well, mainly Lubuntu and Ubuntu) They would not install after selecting "install ubuntu" when prompted via install dvd. It would not go anywhere and eventually error with "internal" error or loop with a black screen and cursor. So I tried to install Lubuntu 14.04 and it worked, but then I tried to update the Distro to 16.04 and it started erroring by looping me back to the login screen(I cannot do anything with this installation now, not even command line).

I'm about to cry here!

What could be going on between 14.04 and 16.04? (I guess a lot)

Would it be ok to use 14.04? I guess I would eventually face this problem anyway though.

Thanks!

Comment: Your description is much too vague to even hazard a guess. 'Internal error' simply meant it's not a syntax error or other non-internal error. 'Loop back to the login screen' usually means a X Server crash, often due to a shoddy graphics card or inappropriate video drivers.  Please try upgrading or installing using a text-based method so you can see and record the errors. Then we can help you better.

Comment: Ok, well I'm sort of a noob here. I don't know how else to install other than CD. I basically don't have a working copy to be able to get into the terminal. Is there a way of getting into terminal and install it through windows? This is a dual boot I am working on and Like I said I cannot do anything with my Lubuntu install now. Could you point me to a site that would teach me how to install via command line? I can't install 16.04 at all. - Thanks

Comment: When you use install DVD, choose 'Try Ubuntu'. Does it work without error? Does it give you a full graphical desktop that you can use? Does networking work?

Comment: If it loads to the "Try ubuntu" menu it errors with the internal error I stated originally. Regardless, it errors to that. - I just tried the install cd again and here is some of the info under more details of the crash report: It's ubiquity 2.21.63.2 - says that is why it's crashing basically - can write more of it down I just cant copy/paste it. (Sorry I accidently hit post)

Comment: What hardware are you trying to install on? Also the ISO you downloaded can be corrupt.

Comment: It's a decent PC. Core i5 and 8 Gigs of RAM - It's about 5 years old. - I verified the CD. And I don't think both Lubuntu and Ubuntu ISO's would both be corrupt.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, well sorry, but I was able to install (new distro) without any problems. I still believe that to be a bug of some sort with the new 16.06 installation CD.

Thanks anyway!